# Convert Swift 3.x to 5.x

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I want to create an UITableview. I found a sample project but its for Swift 3. I´m using Swift 5.x. I could removed nearly all Errors but 1 is remaining and I don't know how to solve it. This is the code

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate,NSTableViewDataSource,NSTableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: NSTableView!

    var dataArray:[NSMutableDictionary] = [["firstName": "Debasis", "lastName": "Das", "fullTimeEmp": 0],
        ["firstName": "Nishant", "lastName": "Singh", "fullTimeEmp": 1],
        ["firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "fullTimeEmp": 1],
        ["firstName": "Jane", "lastName": "Doe", "fullTimeEmp": 1],
        ["firstName": "Mary", "lastName": "Jane", "fullTimeEmp": 0]];

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView!) -> Int
    {
        let numberOfRows:Int = dataArray.count
        return numberOfRows
    }

    private func tableView(tableView: NSTableView!, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn!, row: Int) -> AnyObject!
    {
        let object = dataArray[row] as NSMutableDictionary
        if ((tableColumn.identifier).rawValue == "fullTimeEmp")
        {
            return object[tableColumn.identifier] as? Int? as AnyObject
        }
        else
        {
            return object[tableColumn.identifier] as? String? as AnyObject
        }
    }
    
    private func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, setObjectValue object: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int)
    {
        dataArray[row].setObject(object!, forKey: (tableColumn?.identifier)!)
    }


}
```

[image: Error]

Any Idea how to solve it?

Comment: Why not find a newer tutorial/sample project? This one looks really bad since it's doing everything in the app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick answer to the error you've posted:

Swift can not infer the types of your complex code, So you should help it a bit by replacing it with this:

```
dataArray[row].setObject(object!, forKey: tableColumn!.identifier as NSCopying)
```

## But!

Your code has a lot of issues like:

- unsafe force unwraps
- uncertain unwraps (x?.y)!
- appdelegate unrelated usage.
- etc.

Try more articles and tutorials and monitor your progress step by step ;)

Comment: `(x?.y)!` I hate when I see someone using optional chaining and forcing unwrapping it at the end